# How to change image as shown in this templates?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

i download template from the internet .I m developing a website,please tell me how can i change the icons as shown in image,which is in black and red box shown?
I'm working in visual studio,asp.net.I check all folders of the templates,but i can't found these icons,please help me how can i replace icons?
Here is link of the template image
http://s18.postimg.org/5430kdnnt/Untitled.jpg
here is template link http://www.aspxtemplates.com/template-overview/dotnet/bootstrap1.aspx

Comment: Provide HTML, CSS, Jsfiddle and etc

Comment: I have full template

Comment: I have full template

Comment: I have full template,I don't know which file contains this icons or images

Comment: Post your website link or template

Comment: These icons are coming from a files having extension as `.ttf` or `.wof`. These are truetype fonts so you can find them in **CSS**

Comment: here is template link http://www.aspxtemplates.com/template-overview/dotnet/bootstrap1.aspx

Comment: @Suprabhat how can i change these files?Yes i have fonts folder and also contains .ttf or .wof files

Comment: @HameedKhan you want to change it with an icon image or with a font icon?

Comment: @Suprabhat How??????????????????????

Comment: here is template link can u help me please  aspxtemplates.com/template-overview/dotnet/bootstrap1.aspx –  @Suprabhat

Comment: Can you open a discussion chat i cant help you from comments. Invite me when done.

Comment: I don't know how to open discussion chat?I'm new here please

Comment: I have left you an answer Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your shared link here is how you can change it. Firstly, the icons are coming from font-awesome.min.css and you can find all fonts in a folder named `fonts\font-awesome`.

Now, here in your link all icons are inscribed into `Italic tag` for e.g.

```
<div class="feature-wrap">
    <i class="fa fa-th-list"></i>
    <h2>Menu or Navbar</h2>
    <h3>A standard navigation class navbar navbar-default</h3>
</div>
```

You are find above in your HTML your main concern should be towards `<i class="fa fa-th-list"></i>` this tag for e.g. Here the icons are being created by CSS. Now for this a css has been written in `font-awesome.min.css` for above it's this.

```
.fa-th-list:before {
    content: "\f00b";
}
```

the content section adds the icon. You need to comment this out and replace it with the `backgroud-image`else visit here [Font Awesome Icons](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) and select your favorite icon from here and replace the `<i class="fa fa-th-list"></i>` (e.g.) with the one mentioned there.

Comment: I understand,Thanks,but can u give me example,u choose font and replace code,then i will check,,thnks

Comment: thanksssssssssssssssssssssssss alot,,,thnks its working

Comment: Welcome, If you are satisfied with answer then you can mark this as accepted. If you are still facing any issue you can drop a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

First find the method used to set images (could be set with css styling, or with `img` html tag). For example in Chrome, right click on the element, and choose `Inspect element` from the contextual menu. In the right of the window opened, you will see the stiles and the source file(`.css` file), if that's the case. You should look for `background-image: url(some/path/to/image)`. You can change the path to file inside the css file, or replace the image file itself on the given location.

**EDIT:** Forget the theory about images above. It's set with pseudo elemets `:before` and `:after`, and a special css font, that you can find [here](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/). The css file on the link in your comment is `/css/font-awesome.min.css`.
 You should be able to find `.fa-th:before`, and customize it like this:

```
.fa-th:before {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    content: '';
    background-size: 300px;
    background-image: url("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=a7723f5f7e59"),none;
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: here is link of template http://www.aspxtemplates.com/template-overview/dotnet/bootstrap1.aspx can u help me please,how can i change?